# X button not closing bootstrap error alert

Tags: html, angular, typescript, alert

I have an error div that displays errors:

```
<div *ngIf="isScreenError" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
  <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" (click)='closeAlert()'>×</button>
  ERROR: {{errorMessage.error.message}}</div>
```

The close alert function just sets 'isScreenError' to false.

```
 closeAlert(){
    this.isScreenError=false;
  }
```

Why isn't my div closing? Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Thank you!

Comment: Given the very limited information/code you've provided, nobody will know what you've done wrong here. Please update your question with more relevant code or a [mcve] would be great.

Comment: From the information you've added, there isn't any problem. Check the console for any errors when clicking

Comment: @Narm i updated the code with a function. not sure what other information is neeeded

Comment: @benshabatnoam the console doesn't print any problems. i click on the X and nothing happens

Comment: Add console.log('something') in your `closeAlert` function to see if it hits

Comment: Are you using something other than default change detection? Nothing from the code you've provided stands out as incorrect. If you can reproduce it on something like StackBlitz or similar and share that would help.

Comment: Is the `isScreenError` variable being set to `true` somewhere else? Check for references of it in your component.

Comment: Your code works https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqgdJq
So please give more info about what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score -1):

What kind change detection do you use? Is OnPush?

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

```
enum ChangeDetectionStrategy {
  OnPush: 0
  Default: 1
}

OnPush: 0   
Use the CheckOnce strategy, meaning that automatic change detection is deactivated until reactivated by setting the strategy to Default (CheckAlways). Change detection can still be explicitly invoked. This strategy applies to all child directives and cannot be overridden.
```

If you using OnPush you should start change detection manually.

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges() or markForCheck()

Example:

```js
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'alert',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="isScreenError" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" (click)='closeAlert()'>×</button>
        ERROR: {{errorMessage.error.message}}
    </div>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AlertComponent {
    public errorMessage = {
        error: {
            message: 'Some message'
        }
    };

    public isScreenError = true;

    constructor(
        private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ) { }


    public closeAlert(): void {
        this.isScreenError = false;
        this.cd.markForCheck();
    }

}
```